# Password visible while using SCP?

Tags: linux, rhel, security, password, scp

RHEL8 (default bash shell through ssh)

```
> scp source_path remote_host:destination_path &
> fg
Password: @#$#@#myPassword'sVisibleOhNo!!!
```

First of all, is this just my system, or is it reproducible? It doesn't prompt me for the user and this only happens if I run scp in background (which doesn't make sense in the first place, but still)
Is this expected behavior? Is this not a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not `scp` or the shell which echoes the characters you type, but the kernel according to settings which are given by running programs. (`stty` modify this setting).

If you type `stty -echo`, you will have no echo and need to type (blindly) `stty echo` to revert a normal behaviour.

With `stty -echo &`, bash seems to make the TTY state back in echo mode. It could be the same with `scp`. The behaviour may depends of the shell, but fish and zsh seems to have the same behaviour than bash.

Comment: But it's `ssh` that tells the kernel to put the terminal in non-echoing mode. (Who else but the utility doing the prompting would know if what the user is prompted for should be visible or not?)

Comment: Yes, the shell, when switching between foreground processes should switch the TTY state. I have not the same issue with the command `(stty -echo;read password;stty echo)&`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get some more relevant information due to @Frédéric Loyer 's answer. We can use the following either of the following scripts to see similar behavior to scp.

```
> safe () (stty -echo; read password; stty echo)
> safe &
```

or just

```
> (stty -echo; read password; stty echo)
```

Ultimately, the potential issues (security and otherwise) are not specific to scp, but have to do with bad interactions between `fg` and the shell's echoing settings. These can be manually enabled/disabled using `stty -echo/echo` respectively. This allows us to check the specific behavior on different systems without the need for multiple hosts, an ssh connection, etc.

zsh on MacOS

```
> safe () (stty -echo; read password; stty echo)
> safe &
[1] 12345
>
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  safe
> fg
[1]  + continued  safe
stty: tcsetattr: Interrupted system call
im Getting The Same Issue(macOS zsh now)
>
```

Bash on RHEL and Ubuntu is even worse

```
> (stty -echo; read password; stty echo) &
[1] 12345
> fg
( stty -echo; read password; stty echo )

[1]+  Stopped                 ( stty -echo; read password; stty echo )
> fg
( stty -echo; read password; stty echo )
VisiblePassword!!!
>
```

It becomes completely unresponsive after the first fg. Had to do a ctrl+z and another fg.